# CSS drop down menus links not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I'm trying to get a drop down menu to work with this button so far it's all going well, but when I click on the menu and try to click one of the link's it closes the drop down menu instead of opening the link. Any ideas? (I know there's a way to format this post to have you be able to test the code in this browser, but I'm not sure how to do that)

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>index</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="nav-main">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="nav-item"><img src="images/resume btn.jpg"/></a>
                    <div class="nav-content">
                        <div class="nav-sub">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="www.google.com">Acting</a></li>
                                <li><a href="www.youtube.com">Choreographer/Dancer</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>   
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.nav-main .logo{
    height:40px;
    font-size:1.4em;
    line-height:40px;

}

.nav-main > ul{
    list-style-type:none;

}

.nav-main > ul > li{
    float:left;

}

.nav-content{
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:tan;
    max-height:0;

}

.nav-content a{
color:black;
text-decoration:none;

}

.nav-content a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;

}

.nav-sub ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.nav-sub ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
}

.nav-item:focus ~ .nav-content{
    max-height:400px;
    -webkit-transition:max-height 0.4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:max-height 0.4s ease-in;
    transition:max-height 0.4s ease-in;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using too much elements for task simple as that. Please use this markup:

```
<nav class="nav-main">
    <ul>
        <li>Menu item 1
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://google.com">Sub menu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://youtube.com">Sub menu item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

In this markup use this css:

```
nav ul li ul{display: none; // or whatever code you want for hiding sub menu items}
nav ul li:hover ul{display: block; // or whatever code you want for showing sub menu items}
```

Also, someone already mentioned that you should use 'http://' in links even though its not mandatory.

One more mistake you have made is inside img tag:

```
<img src="images/resume btn.jpg"/>
```

Space between resume & btn is not really cool.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem! I think you and I followed the same video and I checked the comment and someone posted this piece of code and it works! just add it after the other `.nav-content` markup! this was driving me crazy for 2 days straight.

```
.nav-content:active {
   max-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the ">" in the css, example: .nav-menu ul li - also make sure your links have http:// before www

Comment: Originally I had some PDF files in place of the YouTube and Google links. I just put them there as a placeholder. I tried taking out the ">" marks and it doesn't work when I do D:

Comment: try set target="_blank" on the links

Comment: I added it, but the drop down menu still closes out instead of opening the links..

Comment: Sounds like an issue with :focus on .nav-item - try change that to :active

Comment: Also I think your structure looks overly complicated, instead of embedding div inside of the ul and li just set classes and ID's to the objects ie. `<li class="nav-content">`

Comment: I replaced focus with active and now it only shows the drop down menu while I'm clicking on the button itself. I tried replacing it with hover and it only show's the drop down while I'm hovering over the button. Is there anyway to make it stay while I"m inside the drop down element?

Comment: I'm working on it for you now, give me ten mins or so :)

Answer (score -1):

I've isolated the issue to the problem being with the `max-height:0;`. If you comment that out and click on the sub menu options, it should redirect.

With that said I don't know what to change to make the `max-height` work. It's needed since it will hide the submenu. You may need to use jquery.